# Rails 3.2 multiple databases

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

using Rails 3.2.13 I have an application with certain communication devices (say 200 - 300) each of which uses its own MySQL database with naming convention like xy000 + device.id (ie. xy000001, xy000012, etc.). 
Each device (database) has several models (tables) inheriting from ActiveRecord::Base. When a user logges-in to the application, he select a device he wants to work with. Of course, multiple simultaneous users can work with different devices so that the application should be able to connect to multiple databases at one time.

The question is: how can I build the model to make the

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
```

call? How can I select a target database based on user input so that I can work with the same model connected to different database each time?

Hope the explanation is clear. If not, I can be more precise...
Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Create a connection in your database.yml file with the name you would like to use. For instance, if you were to name the connection **products** you might have a connection like the following:

```
products:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: my_database
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: abc123
  host: 127.0.0.1
```

Then in your model, extend ActiveRecord::Base and establish the connection like so:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection :products
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately this approach is not possible. As I said, I have multiple databases with different names. Each model has to connect to a database name based on users' input - thus, in your example, the Product model cannot use the :products adapter because it is fixed to my_database.